# Existence of the inverse limit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Not sure if this question makes much sense but here it goes. For ease, let $I=\mathbb{N}$ and let $n,m \in I$ be s.t. $n<m$. Suppose we have an inverse system $(R_n,f_{mn})$ of commutative rings (with identity). Then, by definition, the set (subgroup of the direct product of $R_n$'s)
\begin{equation}
R=\bigg\{r \in \displaystyle \prod_{m \in I}R_m \bigg|r_n=f_{mn}(r_m) \; \text{for all} \; n \leq m \;  \text{in} \; I\bigg\}
\end{equation}
together with the natural projections is the inverse limit of $(R_n,f_{mn})$. Is it possible that $R$ is *the only one*? That is, given any other cone $K$ of $(R_n,f_{mn})$ there is no isomorphism from $R$ to $K$. Intuitively the answer should be yes but are there any examples of such things?

Comment: Any ring isomorphic to $R$ will produce a counterexample. Any ring has tons of rings isomorphic to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that what you say is the "definition" of the limit is more precisely a *construction*, of an object and maps fitting into a universal mapping property diagram. The latter characterization of the limit allows a very standard proof mechanism, essentially the uniqueness-up-to-unique isomorphism of an initial and/or final object in categories of diagrams, *if* they exist at all.

Thus, in great generality, things characterized by universal properties are unique-up-to-unique-isomorphism, if they exist. (And, now and then, it can happen that the characterization applies to nothing... that is, that the allegedly characterized thing does not exist.)